# Some "chords" do not work with onkeydown (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, keycode

Some keyboard "chords" (combinations of keys pressed simultaneously) will not register properly in the browser (Chrome and Firefox tested). For example, with the code below, try this:

1) press the "e" key (it will log "key 69")

2) while holding down "e", press "]" (it will log "key 221")

3) while still holding down "e" and "]", press "i" (this fails to log!)

4) however, if you let up on "i" and press "o" instead, it will successfully log "key 79".

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode;          
    console.log("key", key);
};
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here, and if there is any sort of workaround?
 For context, I'm developing a QWERTY-based music app, and I'd like to be able to play all my chords.

I'm aware that `keyCode` is deprecated, perhaps this behavior one of the reasons?

What is the right approach for this problem?

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/nt0ad2ap/

Comment: Probably a hardware issue and what the keyboard actually reports to the OS. Your demo works for me on my PC with Chrome 63 but I have a gaming keyboard.

Comment: That's just how typing keyboards work. Not all 3-key combinations can be detected at once. Nothing you can do in JavaScript, nor any other programming language, will change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99.9% sure that's depends on the keyboard's hardware itself. I tried doing <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on a keyboard connected to a laptop and it does not work but when I press <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> on that keyboard and then press <kbd>i</kbd> on the laptop then it works. Keyboard are not usually built to register that many keys at once (aside from <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>) because it is not normally needed. There are special keyboard built mostly for gaming which can register more keys at once. Try googling "anti-ghosting keyboards". Here is a question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-anti-ghosting-for-a-keyboard) about the topic. I have a keyboard which suppose to register 13 keys pressed at once at home. I'll check if the code works with that keyboard in few hours when I get home.

#### UPDATE:

Works fine on a better keyboard. It's a **hardware** problem.

Answer (score 0):

221 is the keyCode for <kbd>]</kbd> and 79 is the keyCode for <kbd>o</kbd> so it's not that you are getting a code that represents the combination of two or more keys pressed at once. So:

1. press the "e" key (it will log "key 69") - *That's OK*
2. while holding down "e", press "]" (it will log "key 221") - *You're getting the code (221) for the last kew pressed <kbd>]</kbd>*
3. while still holding down "e" and "]", press "i" (this fails to
   log!) - *I can't reproduce this scenario, I get code 73 which is the code for <kbd>i</kbd>*
4. however, if you let up on "i" and press "o" instead, it will
   successfully log "key 79". - *You're getting the code for the last kew pressed <kbd>o</kbd>*

If you need to combine keys in JavaScript then you should consider [altKey](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_altkey.asp), [ctrlKey](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_ctrlkey.asp), [shiftKey](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_shiftkey.asp), [metaKey](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_metakey.asp)

[Here's](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keyboard_ctrl_alt_shift.htm) an old example that you may find useful.
Hope it helps.